# What's wrong with my code in python to permutate through different number combinations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've wrote a code to solve a problem like this (There's a number of such problems on some website, but I'm not sure if it's against the rules to post that website here):

> Get [target number] from these numbers given [No.1, No.2, No.3 ...] using basic arithmetic operations (* / - +) and you can only use each number once.

This is my code:

```
from itertools import permutations
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from operator import abs

def evaluate(numbers, operator_sequence): #Takes in a list of numbers and operations to evaluate the value
    return eval("{}".join(str(number) for number in numbers).format(*operator_sequence))


def solve(numbers_given, target):
    operators = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]
    permutated_numbers = list(permutations(numbers_given)) #Permutates the numbers_given
    all_combi = list(combinations_with_replacement(operators, len(numbers_given) - 1)) #Gives all combinations of the operations
    permutations_of_operation_combi = [] 

    for combi in all_combi: #Adds all the different permutations and combinations of operations and add it to permutations_of_operation_combi
        permutated = list(permutations(combi))
        for permutated_functions in permutated:
            if permutated_functions not in permutations_of_operation_combi:
                permutations_of_operation_combi.append(permutated_functions)

    for numbers in permutated_numbers: #Prints the sequence of numbers and operator permutations that equates to the target number
        for operator_sequence in permutations_of_operation_combi:
            value = evaluate(numbers, operator_sequence)
            if int(value) == target and abs(value - target) < 0.01:
                print(" {} ".join(str(number) for number in numbers).format(*operator_sequence))
```

The idea is just to brute force every single permutation and combination of operations and numbers that work to give the target number. However, there's something wrong with this code that I can't see. It gives a solution (and multiple ones at that) to the target number 1042, given the numbers [1, 2, 9, 2, 59, 974] but gives no solution to the target number 770, given the numbers [7, 1, 6, 2, 95, 397]. There might be a slight possibility that the website gives unsolvable puzzles, but I'm pretty sure it's just my code that's not working as intended.

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: what webside do you mean? You could add URL in question (not in comment). Some portals check code also for wrong data. If you think that it should give some solution then you have to debug code - you can use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed.

Comment: @furas Thanks for your reply. The website is [this](http://geniusbrainteasers.com/calculate-number-1042/1363) for the 1042 question and [this](http://geniusbrainteasers.com/calculate-the-number-770/6959) for the 770 question. Sorry I do not understand what you mean by check code for wrong data? My code generates a thousands of lines with print() though, so I don't think it would be very feasible to check through each of them. It works with some questions but not others :(